# How to use timestamp on PHP/MySQL to JSON Google Chart Table

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I am working on a project where I am using Google API Chart, to produce Table Chart by getting data using php, mysql & json. Now I'm stuck on 'synctime' column which is using a timestamp data type on mysql databse which giving me error. What should I use instead of "date"?

Any help is very much appreciated. My codes are below:

```
$sql="SELECT device, recordcount,  CONCAT(city, ', ', country) AS `Country`, synctime FROM devices";
$exec = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    //Labels for the chart, these represent the column titles
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'device', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'recordcount', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Country', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'synctime', 'type' => 'string')
    ); 

$rows = array();
foreach($exec as $row){
    $temp = array();

    //Values
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['device']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['recordcount']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['Country']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (date) $row['synctime']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows; 

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: `date("Y-m-d", $row['synctime'])` or whatever format you need

Comment: Hi @AlexTartan thanks for the help, though the code didn't work for me ,but this gives me the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

First convert your date format and then pass it to array without (date) type or you can define string type.

```
 $getdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , strtotime($row['synctime'])); 
 $temp[] = array('v' => $getdate);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I just modified it a bit and  made it:
    `$temp[] = array('v' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , strtotime($row['synctime'])));`